# UITableView fixed header

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, header

How to disable scrolling for UITableView header, to be always visible? (To have column titles.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I am getting what you mean, are you using a `UITableViewController`?

If you want to have a header that is not scrollable maybe you can try to put a `UIView` at the top of your tableview and add sublayers to it as needed.

If a `tableview` with multiple fixed section headers is what you want, I would suggest using different tableviews and adding `UIViews` on top of each one for the header.

For handling delegate and datasource use `NSObject`'s `- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject` .

For example:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

  if ([tableView isEqual:markosFirstTableView])
  {
     return 1; 
  }

  else 
  {
     return 5;
  }

}
```

Does this help?

Comment: You can compare both instances directly by using the "==" operator, like for example: "tableView == markosFirstTableView". This will compare the memory address of two instances and succeed if those point to the same object.